# Removing lazy var explicit type causes parameter type error

Tags: swift

I'm a little stumped by this one, it seems removing the explicit type on a lazy var is causing a type error in my parameters. Here's the line of code:

```
private lazy var apiBusinessService = DBApiEndPointBusinessService(UIDelegate: self, navigationDelegate: self)
```

I get an error right on that line telling me

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> DBFindATMBusinessService' to expected argument type 'DBApiEndPointBusinessServiceUIDelegate!'
```

Now, I've definitely declared this class as the UIDelegate in a separate extension, and declaring the variable in the following way works:

```
private lazy var apiBusinessService: DBApiEndPointBusinessService = DBApiEndPointBusinessService(UIDelegate: self, navigationDelegate: self)
```

Why would removing the explicit type cause an error in my parameters? I'm not sure at all how to fix this and would greatly appreciate the help.

Edit: So I've read that lazy variables which get evaluated must declare their type explicitly - is using an initializer which sets its delegates considered a case where you need to explicitly declare a type?